# Python scipy DCT on smaller block on image not working

Tags: python, image, numpy, scipy, dct

I am using the scipy.fftpack.dct and scipy.fftpack.idct to an image array in python. I don't however want to apply it to the entire image, but to individual 8x8 blocks in the image. This is the simple class I wrote to for testing this

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import dct, idct

class ImageController():
    def __init__(self, image_name):
        im = np.asarray(Image.open(image_name))
        self.origional_size = im.shape
        im_x_dim, im_y_dim = self.origional_size
        self.image = im
        if not self.image.flags.writeable:
            self.image.flags.writeable = True

    def get(self):
        return self.image

    def display(self):
        Image.fromarray(self.image).show()
        return self

    def apply_dct(self):
        # self.image = dct(self.image, norm='ortho')
        self.loop_through_8_x_8(dct)
        return self

    def apply_idct(self):
        # self.image = idct(self.image, norm='ortho')
        self.loop_through_8_x_8(idct)
        return self

    def loop_through_8_x_8(self, appyFunc):
        print appyFunc
        row = 0
        while row < len(self.image):
            col = 0
            while col < len(self.image[row]):
                self.image[row:row+8, self.get_list(col)] = appyFunc(self.image[row:row+8, self.get_list(col)] , norm='ortho')
                col += 8
            row += 8
        print row, col
        return self;

    def get_list(self, index):
        x = []
        for i in range(index, index + 8):
            x.append(i)
        return x
```

The issue I am having is that when I apply DCT to the 8x8 blocks, then IDCT right afterwards all the information is lost and the image looks like a mess. All I am calling is

```
ImageController('lena.jpg').apply_dct().apply_idct().display()
```

When I run this, the image is all just noise. However if you see in apply_dct() and apply_idct() I have something commented out which is where I tried DCT and IDCT on the entire image instead of on the 8x8 blocks. When I do this it works perfectly, It just doesn't work when I try on the 8x8 blocks, and I need to apply it to the 8x8 blocks and not the entire image.

Extra information if needed, the images are in grey scale so there is only 1 channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the data type of your image array (`self.image.dtype`).  It is probably 8 bit unsigned integers.  The DCT will be floating point values, but when you assign the result of the DCT to the 8x8 block *in place*, the floating point values are cast to 8 bit integers.  Then the same thing happens when you apply the IDCT.

One option to avoid the problem is to convert the image to 64 bit floating point in `__init__()`, e.g, `im = np.asarray(Image.open(image_name), dtype=np.float64)`.  Whether that makes sense depends on what else you are going to do with the array.